# Get cell DisplayName from strongly-typed-list cell by List only (empty list)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a list of **"Book"** (e.g.) as a model in view

```
@model List<Book>
```

I want to create a table that each column get it's header by Book's DisplayName propery:

```
<tr>
        <th class="text-right">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.someMetaData.lineNumber)
        </th>
        <th class="text-right">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => Model.someMetaData.FirstName)
        </th>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DisplayNameFor` helper method when your model is of type `IEnumerable<T>`

```
@model IEnumerable<Book>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(a=>a.Id)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(a => a.Name)</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var b in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@b.Id</td>
        <td>@b.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

This works only if your view is strongly typed to an `IEnumerable<Book>`, It will not work for `List<Book>`